# Array with addresses

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, bigint

I have a problem with my code. I tried to implement big integers (bigger than the normal) and all went fine.

I chose to represent them as dynamic arrays. So, the function receives a pointer for shorts (to use less memory; I could use char that uses 1 byte, but short is fine) and sets it to the dynamic array.

On my main function, I have an array (of short pointers) that will have the addresses of (arrays of) various numbers. The problem is when I try to  compare the number that is currently on my pointer and another on the array. Whenever I try to assign that address to a pointer, for comparison, I get a warning from the compiler saying:

```
cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

The pointer I'm trying to assign the address is also a pointer for short.
Tries:

```
short *p = arr[0];

short *p = (void *) arr[0];

short *p = (short *) arr[0];
```

@edit

Array is defined as `short *arr[SIZE];`

Because this is a warning, the program has compiled, but when try to run it I get a `Segmentation fault(core dumped)` error, as expected.

What is the best solution?

@edit 2:

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bigint.h"

#define SIZE 10000

int isInArr(short *p, short **arr, int length){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(equalBig(arr[i], p)){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void freeMem(short **arr, int length){
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        free(arr[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    short *p, *numbers[SIZE] = { NULL };
    int a, b, count = 0;

    p = malloc(sizeof(short)*BIG_INT);

    for(a = 2; a <= 100; a++){
        for(b = 2; b <= 100; b++){
            powerBig(p, a, b);

            if(!isInArr(p, numbers, count)){
                numbers[count] = p;
                createBig(&p);
                count++;
            }else{
                clearBig(p);
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", count);

    freeMem(numbers, count);

    return 0;
}
```

bigint.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "bigint.h"


/* Type Big Integer */

void createBig(short **pointer){ /* Constructor */
    *pointer = malloc(sizeof(short)*BIG_INT);

    clearBig(*pointer);

    **pointer = STOP;
}

void clearBig(short *pointer){ /* Put 0's on ALL places of the array */
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < BIG_INT; i++){
        *(pointer+i) = 0;
    }
}

void powerBig(short *p, int a, int b){ /* Operation - power */
    int i = 0, j, digit = 0, rem;
    short *tmp = malloc(sizeof(short)*BIG_INT); /* Variable for temporary allocation of array during product */
    short base[4]; /* Variable for base */
    short *q = base;

    while(a != 0){ /* Put a in an array */
        *(p + i) = a % 10;
        *(q + i) = a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
        i++;
    }

    *(p + i) = STOP;
    *(q + i) = STOP;

    for(i = 1; i < b; i++){
        digit = 0;
        clearBig(tmp);
        while(*(q + digit) != STOP){
            rem = 0;
            j = 0;

            while(*(p + j) != STOP){
                rem += (*(p + j)) * (*(q + digit));
                rem += *(tmp + j + digit);
                *(tmp + j + digit) = rem % 10;
                rem /= 10;
                j++;
            }

            if(rem != 0){
                *(tmp + j + digit) = rem % 10;
                j++;
            }

            *(tmp + j + digit) = STOP;

            digit++;
        }
        copyBig(tmp, p); /* Update the p array */
    }
    free(tmp);
}

void copyBig(short *orig, short *dest){ /* Move big integer to another array */
    int i;
    for(i = 0; *(orig+i) != STOP; i++){
        *(dest+i) = *(orig+i);
    }
    *(dest+i) = STOP;
}

int equalBig(short *p, short *q){
    int i = 0;

    if(p == NULL || q == NULL){
        return 0;
    }

    while(*(q + i) != STOP && *(p + i) != STOP){
        if(*(p + i) != *(q + i)){
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return (*(q + i) ==  *(p + i)) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
--20748-- REDIR: 0x401cfd0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x3809e181 (???)
--20748-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
--20748--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so ..
--20748--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 2567ccf6 wanted 49420590)
--20748--    object doesn't have a symbol table
--20748-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
--20748--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so ..
--20748--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 0e27c9a8 wanted ac585421)
--20748--    object doesn't have a symbol table
==20748== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--20748--     old: 0x0401cfd0 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x3809e181 ???
--20748--     new: 0x0401cfd0 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c31020 strlen
--20748-- REDIR: 0x401b920 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x4c30bc0 (index)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x401bb40 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4c320d0 (strcmp)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x401dd30 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c35270 (mempcpy)
--20748-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
--20748--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so ..
--20748--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 7a8ee3e4 wanted a5190ac4)
--20748--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so ..
--20748--   .. CRC is valid
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ec9a00 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ec5280 (libc.so.6:strcspn) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ecbcf0 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ec76f0 (libc.so.6:strpbrk) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ec7a80 (libc.so.6:strspn) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ec914b (libc.so.6:memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ec7400 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x4c308a0 (rindex)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ec91b0 (libc.so.6:memset) redirected to 0x4a286f0 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4fac970 (libc.so.6:__memset_avx2) redirected to 0x4c344c0 (memset)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ebe130 (libc.so.6:malloc) redirected to 0x4c2db20 (malloc)
--20748-- REDIR: 0x4ebe4f0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2ed80 (free)
==20748== Invalid write of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400B54: powerBig (bigint.c:60)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae1032 is 0 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x400913: powerBig (bigint.c:26)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748== 
==20748== Invalid read of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400C0F: copyBig (bigint.c:71)
==20748==    by 0x400B8C: powerBig (bigint.c:64)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae1032 is 0 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x400913: powerBig (bigint.c:26)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748== 
==20748== Invalid write of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400C28: copyBig (bigint.c:74)
==20748==    by 0x400B8C: powerBig (bigint.c:64)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae0e52 is 0 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x40087C: createBig (bigint.c:9)
==20748==    by 0x4007DD: main (20.c:39)
==20748== 
==20748== Invalid read of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400AE2: powerBig (bigint.c:47)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae1212 is 0 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x40087C: createBig (bigint.c:9)
==20748==    by 0x4007DD: main (20.c:39)
==20748== 
==20748== Invalid read of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400A6A: powerBig (bigint.c:49)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae13f2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x400913: powerBig (bigint.c:26)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748== 
==20748== Invalid write of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400AB0: powerBig (bigint.c:50)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae13f2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x400913: powerBig (bigint.c:26)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748== 
==20748== Invalid write of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400B34: powerBig (bigint.c:56)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae13f4 is 2 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x400913: powerBig (bigint.c:26)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748== 
==20748== Invalid read of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400BF5: copyBig (bigint.c:72)
==20748==    by 0x400B8C: powerBig (bigint.c:64)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae13f2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x400913: powerBig (bigint.c:26)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748== 
==20748== Invalid write of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400BF8: copyBig (bigint.c:72)
==20748==    by 0x400B8C: powerBig (bigint.c:64)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae1212 is 0 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x40087C: createBig (bigint.c:9)
==20748==    by 0x4007DD: main (20.c:39)
==20748== 
==20748== Invalid read of size 2
==20748==    at 0x400A31: powerBig (bigint.c:48)
==20748==    by 0x400794: main (20.c:35)
==20748==  Address 0x5ae15d2 is 0 bytes after a block of size 402 alloc'd
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x40087C: createBig (bigint.c:9)
==20748==    by 0x4007DD: main (20.c:39)
==20748== 
--20748-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - exiting
--20748-- si_code=1;  Faulting address: 0x6112E58;  sp: 0x808ca9e30

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal

host stacktrace:
==20748==    at 0x38091C12: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==20748==    by 0x38050E84: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==20748==    by 0x38051056: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==20748==    by 0x380D4F7B: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==20748==    by 0x380E3946: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 20748)
==20748==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20748==    by 0x40087C: createBig (bigint.c:9)
==20748==    by 0x4007DD: main (20.c:39)
```

Comment: How is `arr` defined?

Comment: short *arr[SIZE];

Comment: So, it's an array of short pointers?

Comment: I suppose it is. I want to save there the addresses of a short pointer

Comment: How is it actually used? like where did it crash?

Comment: `arr` is an array of pointer of `short`. What exactly is `p` supposed to be?

Comment: If `arr` is declared that way, then `short *p = arr[0];` is the correct one, where `p`  points at the first pointer in `arr`.

Comment: Added code, for better understanding

Comment: Perhaps the error is here `createBig(&p);`, you are passing a pointer of `p` to `createBig`. Are you doing `realloc` on that pointer?

Comment: @Pablo. No I'm doing a new `malloc` and clearing all the spaces on that array.

Comment: `short *q = (void *) arr[0];` is just wrong, `arr[0]` is `short`, you are treating the short as an address. `short *q = arr;` is more than enough. And you don't even need that temp variable, you can pass `arr` to `equalBig`.

Comment: forgot to try that. Now it doesn't give me a single warning, but gives crash on malloc. I guess that is because I never free the memory.

Comment: I don't think it's that, show us the functions, otherwise we can only speculate.

Comment: Done. Don't mind if the numbers are on reverse order. If I want to output it I can do it normally.

Comment: Your `powerBig` might also have UB, depending how large `j` and `digit` get, `*(p + j)` and `*(p + digit)` might access `base` out of bounds. And your `copyBig` can be swapped with `memcpy(p, tmp, BIG_INT * sizeof *p)`.

Comment: I retracted my answer because you pointed out that in the first iteration `count` is 0, so nothing gets compared, I'll have to take a closer look again at the things you do. What I don't get is what is `powerBig` trying to do?

Comment: It does what it is meant to do. It is the `pow()` applied to bigger integers. But there's a thing, the value is "upside down". So if I make `powerBig(p, 5,2)` I'll get the output (full array): `5299000...`

Comment: 'j' and 'digit' will never go out of bounds, because this is a specific implementation for this program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, `isInArr` checks if the contents of `p` are already in `numbers`. Then you have
pass a pointer to `numbers`, for that you have to change the `isInArr` function
to:

```
int isInArr(short *p, short **arr, int length){
    int i;

    if(length >= SIZE)
        length = SIZE; // checking that you don't access `arr` out of bounds

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(equalBig(arr[i], p)){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and in `main` you call it:

```
if(!isInArr(p, numbers, count)){
```

because you want to search through the whole `numbers` array. I also would
declare `numbers` like this:

```
short *numbers[SIZE] = { NULL };
```

so that all pointers are initialized in as `NULL`, in `equalBig` you can add an
extra check `if(p == NULL || q == NULL) return 0;` to guard against `NULL`
pointers.

---

**edit**

> *OP wrote in comments*
>
> the output is: 
>   `20.c: In function ‘isInArr’: 20.c:11:15: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘equalBig’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] if(equalBig(arr[i], p)){ ^ In file included from 20.c:3:0: bigint.h:8:5: note: expected ‘short int ’ but argument is of type ‘short int’ int equalBig(short *p, short *q); / Compare */ ^`

I guess you still have a small error somewhere in the code, some variable that
is still has the wrong type.

I can compile and run this code (which has my fixes) without a problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define STOP 99

int equalBig(short *p, short *q){
    int i = 0;

    while(*(q + i) != STOP && *(p + i) != STOP){
        if(*(p + i) != *(q + i)){
            return 0;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return (*(q + i) ==  *(p + i)) ? 1 : 0;
}

int isInArr(short *p, short **arr, int length){
    int i;

    if(length >= SIZE)
        length = SIZE; // checking that you don't access `arr` out of bounds

    for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(equalBig(arr[i], p)){
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    short *p, *numbers[SIZE] = { NULL };

    numbers[0] = calloc(10, sizeof *numbers[0]);
    numbers[1] = calloc(10, sizeof *numbers[1]);
    p = calloc(10, sizeof *p);

    numbers[0][3] = STOP;
    numbers[1][4] = STOP;
    p[4] = STOP;

    printf("isInArr: %d\n", isInArr(p, numbers, 2));

    free(numbers[0]);
    free(numbers[1]);
    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

```
$ gcc a.c -oa -g -Wall
$ valgrind ./a 
==10955== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10955== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10955== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10955== Command: ./a
==10955== 
isInArr: 1
==10955== 
==10955== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10955==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10955==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 1,084 bytes allocated
==10955== 
==10955== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10955== 
==10955== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10955== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: yes, numbers[0] is uninitialized, but it won't get into `equalBig()` because of length, that is 0, at that time.

Comment: I use malloc a lot of times, because I want to save the value that is stored dinamically

Comment: @MoonWalker oh I see, then the `free` in `createBig` is not necessary. I'll update my answer

Comment: about the short thing, I forgot to change here sorry

Comment: @MoonWalker I made an update of my answer, I think the problem was how you declared `isInArr` and how you called. At first I didn't understand the meaning of `numbers`, I overlooked the lines `numbers[count] = p; createBig(&p); count++;` because I was focused on the other functions, that help me understand what you are doing.

Comment: this is for a well known challenge on the Internet. I won't mention it so Google cannot find this solution.

Comment: and length will never be bigger than SIZE. I can tell you why. I set SIZE = 10000, because it is the maximum number of bigints I can get. But then this code makes `2⁴` which is the same as `4²`, so length will be, at most 9999, because I don't want repeated numbers.

Comment: the output is:

`20.c: In function ‘main’:
20.c:39:19: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘isInArr’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    if(!isInArr(p, numbers[0], count)){
20.c:7:5: note: expected ‘short int **’ but argument is of type ‘short int *’
 int isInArr(short *p, short **arr, int length){`

Comment: *and length will never be bigger than SIZE* having this sanity checks doesn't hurt either, it's a good practice to do this kind of checks, even if you know that the `length` is never going to be larger than `SIZE`. You get accustomed to write robust code.

Comment: *the output is ... ` strange, you must have an error still somewhere. I've updated my answer showing you that may fixes work.

Comment: Program crash and gives weird `malloc` message. Just a sec

Comment: Output: `*** Error in \`./20': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00000000023467f0 ***
20: malloc.c:2394: sysmalloc: Assertion \`(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) ==0)' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: Can you run it through a debugger or valgrind? I don't see any errors in your other functions (other than `isInArr` and that you don't check if `malloc` returns `NULL`). This smells like undefined behaviour somewhere else, perhaps `powerBig`?

Comment: @MoonWalker just an advice, if there are already answer, please don't change your code, otherwise the answer may not make any sense.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but the answer is not correct. It needs to be improved, so as the code

Comment: I put all your code in a big file and compiled it, when I run in `valgrind` I get the first error here: *Invalid write of size 2, at 0x108ABA: powerBig (b.c:63)*,  line 63 is `*(tmp + j + digit) = STOP;`

Comment: @MoonWalker what is the real value of `BIG_INT`?  before `*(tmp + j + digit) = STOP;` I added this line: `printf("j(%d) + digit(%d) = %d\n", j, digit, j + digit);` and it's printing values like this: `j(202) + digit(2) = 204` and I defined `BIG_INT` as 200. As you see here, the code **is accessing** out of bounds as I said it would.

Comment: BIGINT is 202. Will try that.

Comment: @MoonWalker add this line `if(j+digit >= BIG_INT) printf("j(%d) + digit(%d) = %d, access out of bounds\n", j, digit, j + digit);` before `*(tmp + j + digit) = STOP;` I changed `BIG_INT` to 202, and I get two "access out of bounds" prints before it crashes. I told you, you might access out of bounds, so check `powerBig`, perhaps you've made a logic error there. I'm going now to bed, I'll take a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: I tried to allocate 10 bytes more in the `tmp` array and it gives the another error. `*** Error in \`./20': munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000a6c7f0 ***`

Comment: @MoonWalker I cannot take a closer look right now (@work), but my suspicion is that `j+digit` will be bigger than `BIG_INT`. What you have to do is to determine for which `a` and `b` this behaviour can be observed and then try to understand why it happens for these values.

Comment: @MoonWalker With the value `a==100` and `b==68`, you get in `powerBig`: `i==67, j==202, i+j==269` which overflows `tmp`. When I defined `BIG_INT` to 300, then everything worked without a problem, `BIG_INT` at 202 is just to small.

Comment: I came to the value 200 because the maximum value it could be was 100^100, so log(100^100) = 200

Comment: it works, but BIG_INT needs to be 301, because there is an overflow due to STOP value